# Create a Registry Script That Adds A 32-Bit DWORD Value

Tags: regedit

I'm trying to create a registry script that users can double click and it adds a 32-bit DWORD value to the registry.

The objective is to add EnableARIATelemetryFeature with a value of 0 to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync

So far, I am able to do it in the Command Line which is REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync /v EnableARIATelemetryFeature /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

Can anyone translate it into a .Reg Script so Users can just double click?

Thanks!
Krauser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can translate it to a .reg script by "exporting" the registry branch using either `reg export` or `regedit` tools, then editing out all unneeded values to leave just the one.

According to the [.reg file specification](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310516/how-to-add-modify-or-delete-registry-subkeys-and-values-by-using-a-reg):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync]
"EnableARIATelemetryFeature"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this was exactly what I was looking for!